# Update parameters during ffmpeg encoding process is running

Tags: c++, linux, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I want to update parameters like fps, bitrate, gop of video encoder which were already passed to AVCodecContext structure previously.I want to get it's reflection at same time whenever I update any parameters.

One thing can be done, is that need to close codec using av codec close and again open it.

But I think that is not good way.

Here is my ffmpeg's source code for video encoding:

```
        int got_output = 0, ret = 0;
        //av_init_packet(&pkt);
        pkt.data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
        pkt.size = 0;
        ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
                cerr << "Error sending a frame for encoding\n";
                exit(1);
        }
```

Is there any FFMPEG's API that can be used to reload encoding parameters?

Comment: Why are you trying to change coding parameters during an encode? That will result in corrupted media.

Comment: There are many parameters that can be changed on the fly without corrupting the media.

Answer (score 0):

No, FFmpeg does not have an API for a running process. It is something you would need to develop yourself.